# Как правильно построить страницу на vue js?

Tags: vue.js

Создал проект vue js.

В папке **src** есть такие файлы:

```
- Header.vue
- main.js
```

Содержимое файла **Header.vue**:

```
<template><div id="header">HEADER</div></template>
<script> export default { name: 'Header' } </script>
```

Содержимое файла **main.js**:

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import Header from './Header'
Vue.config.productionTip = false
    new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    router,
    components: { Header },
    template: '<Header/>'
})
```

В итоге на страницу вывело надпись HEADER.

Тут все ок.

Теперь хотел добавить на эту же страницу вывод FOOTER.

Для этого я создал в папке **src** файл **Footer.vue** с таким кодом:

```
<template><div id="footer">FOOTER</div></template>
<script> export default { name: 'Footer' } </script>
```

И изменил код **main.js** вот так:

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import Header from './Header'
import Footer from './Footer'

Vue.config.productionTip = false

new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    router,
    components: { Header, Footer },
    template: '<Header/><Footer/>'
})
```

В итоге FOOTER не появился...

Что я делаю не так?

Comment: Перепишите тэг Header как положено: `<Header></Header>`

Comment: @Дмытрык `template: '<Header></Header><Footer/>'` - не помогло

Comment: Не надо создавать компоненты с именами стандартных тегов. `import CustomHeader from './Header.vue'`, а потом вставлять как `<custom-header/>`

Comment: @AlexSazonov, точно)

Comment: Компоненты во Vue должны иметь составные имена: `<my-header>`, `<base-footer>` - что-нибудь такое.

Comment: @smellyshovel не должны. Хоть из одной буквы имя. Главное, чтобы не дублировало теги из спеки html.

Comment: А вообще не обязательно подобные вещи выделять в отдельные компоненты. Можете включить один какой-нибудь `App.vue` и в нем использовать стандартные `<header>`, `<footer>` и т.д. Но, конечно, зависит  от ваших потребностей.

Comment: @AlexSazonov https://vuejs.org/v2/style-guide/#Multi-word-component-names-essential - не обязаны, но очень рекомендуется

Comment: @Дмытрык сделал так: `template: '<custom-header></custom-header><custom-footer></custom-footer>'` - но не вижу FOOTER, только HEADER

Answer (score 0):

Рекомендую создать **App.vue** и в него импортировать `header` и `footer`, а не через **main.js**.

Тогда файл **App.vue** будет иметь вид:

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <Header/>
    ...
    <Footer/>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import Header from "./components/Header";
import Footer from "./components/Footer";

export default {
  name: "App",
  components: {
    Header,
    Footer
  }
};
</script>
```

А **main.js**:

```
import Vue from "vue";
import App from "./App.vue";

Vue.config.productionTip = false;

new Vue({
  render: h => h(App)
}).$mount("#app");
```

[Пример простейшей структуры проекта в CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/vue-template-txdhm?fontsize=14)